# Ellakcy moodle-compose repo: Used the solution but I get 303 redirect loop

Tags: docker, docker-compose, moodle, env

I used the docker-moodle solution offered from [ellkcy's repository](https://github.com/ellakcy/moodle-compose) that used their built docker [images](https://hub.docker.com/r/ellakcy/moodle/). But for some reason I get a 303 redirect loop and the browser fails to load the moodle.

Over my `.env` I have setup the following settings

```
# In case of a reverse proxy please change the following setting
# It should have the url that the USER provides into her/his browser.

MOODLE_URL=https://example.com:8082

# Database configuration
MOODLE_DB_USER=moodle
MOODLE_DB_PASSWORD=somepasswd
MOODLE_DB_NAME=moodle

# Default user
MOODLE_ADMIN=admin
MOODLE_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
MOODLE_ADMIN_EMAIL=fakepasswd

# Indicate whether runs Behind SSL Proxy (set values in true  by default are set as false)
MOODLE_REVERSE_LB="true"
MOODLE_SSL="true"

#mail settings
MOODLE_EMAIL_TYPE_QMAIL=false # Set true is qmail MTA a used
MOODLE_EMAIL_HOST=mail.example.com
```

As you can see I have set the `MOODLE_REVERSE_LB` and the `MOODLE_SSL` into `true` value. But does not seem to be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mention:

> "But does not seem to be the issue."

Well it **IS** the issue because the `MOODLE_REVERSE_LB` and the `MOODLE_SSL` have their values in quotes therefore the configuration may not recognize them as valid booleans.

I would suggest as this [link](https://github.com/ellakcy/docker-moodle) mentions to remove the quotes and the `.env` should be:

```
# In case of a reverse proxy please change the following setting
# It should have the url that the USER provides into her/his browser.

MOODLE_URL=https://example.com:8082

# Database configuration
MOODLE_DB_USER=moodle
MOODLE_DB_PASSWORD=somepasswd
MOODLE_DB_NAME=moodle

# Default user
MOODLE_ADMIN=admin
MOODLE_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
MOODLE_ADMIN_EMAIL=fakepasswd

# Indicate whether runs Behind SSL Proxy (set values in true  by default are set as false)
MOODLE_REVERSE_LB=true
MOODLE_SSL=true

#mail settings
MOODLE_EMAIL_TYPE_QMAIL=false # Set true is qmail MTA a used
MOODLE_EMAIL_HOST=mail.example.com
```

Please emphasize into the:

```
MOODLE_REVERSE_LB=true
MOODLE_SSL=true
```

As you can see true is **unquoted**. Also if does not help you you can try to use the `1` value and that will result tho the following `.env`:

```
# In case of a reverse proxy please change the following setting
# It should have the url that the USER provides into her/his browser.

MOODLE_URL=https://example.com:8082

# Database configuration
MOODLE_DB_USER=moodle
MOODLE_DB_PASSWORD=somepasswd
MOODLE_DB_NAME=moodle

# Default user
MOODLE_ADMIN=admin
MOODLE_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
MOODLE_ADMIN_EMAIL=fakepasswd

# Indicate whether runs Behind SSL Proxy (set values in true  by default are set as false)
MOODLE_REVERSE_LB=1
MOODLE_SSL=1

#mail settings
MOODLE_EMAIL_TYPE_QMAIL=false # Set true is qmail MTA a used
MOODLE_EMAIL_HOST=mail.example.com
```

As you can see in the `MOODLE_REVERSE_LB` and in the `MOODLE_SSL` environmental variables I used the value `1`.